# upload data from an iphone app to a web server with php

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, xcode, networking

with almost no knowledge in PHP whatsoever, I am trying to send some data (NSData) from my iphone app to my web server (locally for now) but without success (The PHP uploader script is being called since I am getting its error message). could anyone please help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

My iphone app at this point includes only the code below in the ViewDidLoad of my (one and only) viewController, which I have combined from some of the conversations around here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

  NSData *data;    
const char *bytestring = "black dog";
data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:bytestring length:strlen(bytestring)];
NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/uploader1.php";
NSString *filename = @"filename";
NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);

}
```

I have also tried the following PHP uploader script:

```
  <?php
    $target = "./upload/";
        $target = $target.basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']) ;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong and how come I cant post this data? Again, the PHP script is getting called cause I get the error message: Wrong file type...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I could be wrong as I don't own an iphone to play with :( but `NSString *urlString` should be accessible, so unless you iphone is connected on your lan it would always fail. also both them options for serverside upload script are bad. Option 1 moves the uploaded file without any checks on validity, opening your server to whatever nastys someone can think up. Option 2 only displays the post values, the file is never moved from temp dir to somewhere accessible..

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence. Is there any better implementation that you recommend on? For now I am testing locally, and just want to see the data locally on my machine, then I will take care of making it more secure. Any advice on improving the PHP script would be welcome.

Comment: You did not tell what the error message you are getting? Put your php script to any server(should not be local server) and make request to get response back.

Comment: I am getting the error from the PHP script - in this case 'No' (see above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Objective-C code you are sending the file like this:

```
 name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",
```

so, in the PHP side, you should access `$_FILES["userfile"]`, instead of `$_FILE["file"]` or `$_FILE["uploaded"]`, to get the correct information about your upload.

If you are still experiencing problems, first suggestion is putting some traces server-side:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

will give you a list of all the $_POST/$_GET/cookies input parameters, so you can better know what is happening. Furthermore, I would suggest also tracing:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

it could be that the ObjC side is sending wrong data, or that wrong data is read on the server side.

EDIT: the error you are getting:

```
"Wrong file type..."
```

depends on the fact that you are trying to calculate the size of the uploaded file as if it were an image:

```
 $check = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
 if($check[0]>0 && $check[1]>0 && $check['mime']=='image/jpg'){
```

while in fact you are sending a simple string as file content:

```
 const char *bytestring = "black dog";
```

either you remove the check, or you upload a real file.

EDIT:

Use these lines:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

to make error reporting more verbose, so you possibly know *why* it is failing...

Comment: this is what i get for $_FILES: Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => filename.txt
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /private/var/tmp/php5HSwH0
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 9
        )

)

Comment: and for ($_REQUEST):Array
(
)

Comment: True - I just found out about it and removed the check altogether. still nothing changes....:(

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect my current PHP file

Comment: use this: `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], './upload/')) {`; `move_uploaded_file` gets the destination directory as second argument (not destination file name); please, ensure also that it exists and the web server has write rights.

Comment: still nothing...just to make sure: the location of the upload library should be where the uploader.php is, right? it does exist there and all write permissions are there...

Comment: it should... but it seems that the blocking point is there... see my edit also...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try ASIHTTPRequest?
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Well, if you get that compiling properly, image upload is 5 lines of code. You should include CFNetwork, MobileCoreServices, libz.dydlib on a bare minimum.

Comment: I did all that, but using the beta xcode, maybe thats the reason?

Answer (score 0):

For target path dont use HTTP, use the method below.

Instead of doing `file_put_contents(***WebSiteURL***...)` you need to use the server path to `/cache/lang/file.php` (e.g. /home/content/site/folders/filename.php).

You cannot open a file over HTTP and expect it to be written. Instead you need to open it using the local path.